# Почему закрыли мой вопрос на английском StackOverflow?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

[Why I get empty json response {} using api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffer/v1?key={key}&tradeofferid={offerid}&language=en_us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910622)

Мне очень нужно получить ответ на мой вопрос. Я предоставил достаточно информации и разжевал все для самых непонятнливых. Я не нашел подоходящего существующего ответа. У меня есть некоторая репутация - и все равно кто посчитал что мой вопрос надо закрыть без обьяснения причин - это возмутительно!

Comment: Не по теме, но без форматирования, он нечитаем ..

Comment: Такой вопрос можно закрывать уже из-за совершенно нечитаемого заголовка.

Comment: исправил все что мог. Я уже не знаю что еще можно улучшить

Answer (score 1):

0. А почему ты тут спрашиваешь, почему там закрыли твой вопрос?
1. Потому что там любят всё закрывать.
2. Потому что вопрос по api стима, а не по программированию?
3. Потому что ты не приложил никакого кода, т. е. единственный возможный ответ, что апи использовано неверно.

Comment: `Потому что там любят всё закрывать.` — +100 ;)